# Can't access Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, initramfs-tools

I recently sent my Acer Nitro 5 Laptop to be repaired, and they said that they had changed the motherboard and the RAM.

I had a dual boot Windows + Kali Linux. Now that my laptop is back, I can boot Windows without a problem, but Kali doesn't work. It is stuck on `initramfs`, saying `Problem loading X.509 certificate -65`. I tried fixing the problem with a Live Ubuntu, but it didn't detect any of my two hard drives so it was impossible to do anything on them... However, I know that my hard drives are not broken because from the grub I could see the list of files in it...

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to "repair" it and boot Kali as before?
2. If it is impossible, is there a way to recover the files from my Kali HD?

Comment: A new motherboard has the default uEFI settings. That's what you should check before anything else and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Looks like linux is unable to find the MOK, did you have secure boot enabled and enrolled?

Comment: @mashuptwice nope, secure boot disabled

Answer (score 0):

For the **second** question, the problem came from the Intel RST. I don't know why, but changing the SATA mode to AHCI allowed me to access the hard drives from Live Ubuntu. However, I didn't find any solution for the `initramfs` problem, so I just recovered my data and reinstalled Linux.

Answer (score -3):

Was the motherboard and RAM replaced with the exact models as were there
before?

If the repairers didn't touch the hard disks, then this truly looks like
the installed RAM does not fit the new motherboard,
and that Linux is more sensitive to the problem than Windows.

If you wish us to verify the compatibility of the installed hardware,
please supply the motherboard exact model and that of the RAM.

For saving the files, you could perhaps do it from Windows,
by using WSL2 with
[Kali Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/kali-linux/9pkr34tncv07?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
to access the disks.